# Replacing text in table with an array using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Jquery V1.11.1 and I want to replace all of the TD elements in my HTML table from the third row from left. I'm using an array which values must be passed in each TD element of the table.

```
var numberArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

$.each(numberArray , function(index, value){
    $("table tr td:nth-child(3)").html(value);
});
```

This returns in every TD element a 5. How can I make it like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 per TD tag.

Comment: Could you provide us your HTML?

Comment: "third row from left" do you mean "column"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function(index){
    $(this).html(numberArray[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var numberArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

        $.each(numberArray , function(index, value){
            $("table tr td:nth-child("+index+")").html(value);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you want to update value of 3rd row with array

```
var numberArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
$.each(numberArray , function(index, value){
    var td=value+1;
    $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child("+td+")").html(value);
});
```

[<kbd>Updated DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/LZyQ9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var numberArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
$.each(numberArray , function(index, value){
    $("table tr td:nth-child("+index+")").html(value);
});
```